# accessing deleted documents jsonstore

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

If I remove documents from a collection using accessor.remove(), is it possible for me to find them again as long as they are not physically deleted, or to undelete them?
For exemple, that they do not get returned by findAll but get returned by queries like {identifier:identifier_value}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getPushRequired` API will return those documents. They can be filtered using the `_deleted` attribute.

Comment: The `push` API will physically remove them after they have been sent to an adapter.

Comment: The getPushRequired API returns all the dirty documents and not only the deleted ones. I believe the _deleted attribute which I just found out about should be part of the answer.

Comment: That is correct, the `_deleted` key will tell you if the document was removed or not.